# What is React.js Equivalent for Jquery .html()

Tags: reactjs, virtual-dom

I am trying to append Html Content on to a DOM Element using React.js 
I would like to do it in React rather then access the DOM using jquery

var DOMNode = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.contentEdit);
 $(DOMNode).html(this.props.html);

how can I write this using purely react

Comment: `document.querySelector(s).innerHTML = this.props.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to, you can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML, but you should make sure the HTML you're passing in is sanitized properly: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html